# How To Create A Dynamically Sized TextArea In Android Javascript

Tags: javascript, android

In my app a user inputs a certain distance in the form of feet and inches. After submission, I need to draw a square `textarea` in the center of the screen, where the user will then be able to manually adjust the size of the text to match the height of the box. This needs to be able to work across various screen sizes and densities. The app runs on TV's. How can I accomplish this in javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this with a little bit of math. In order to create the box at the right height, I first had to find the screen `PPI` (Pixels Per Inch). I did this by requiring the user to input the value (in inches) of the screens diagonal. I then used the Pythagorean theorem like the following.

`float PPI = (float)Math.sqrt((double)(ScreenX * ScreenX + ScreenY * SceenY))/Diagonal`

From here it was as easy as setting the desired height in inches and multiplying it by `PPI`, hope this helps!